# A big space on my HTML file "Portfolio" Section

Tags: html, css

I have a website here: http://desertcinema.com/

Under the "Portfolio" section there is a big space from w/c I don't know where it is coming from.

[BIG SPACE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67lem.jpg)

I have no idea where this is coming from. Do you know what should I add on my HTML or remove on my CSS to do so? Here's my HTML on that part:

```
    <h1>OUR PORTFOLIO</h1><div class="subtext-top">CLIENT-FOCUSED MEDIA PRODUCTION</div><div class="line-dark1"></div>



</div>



</div></div><div class="row">

<div class="sixteen columns wpb_column column_container"   >
    <div  class="wpb_wrapper ">
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="sixteen columns">
                <div id="portfolio-filter">
                    <ul id="filter">
                        <li><a href="#" class="current" data-filter="*" title=""></a></li><li><a href="#" data-filter=".photography" title="">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li><li><a href="#" data-filter=".video-production" title="">VIDEO PRODUCTION</a></li></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="portfolio-wrap isotope">
            <li class="portfolio-box video-production ">
                <a class="vimeo" href="https://vimeo.com/169312968&autoplay=true" title="iLiveAccountable">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/ilive-1-31nfbcra0szpkeu8rwwxz4.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                    <h4>iLiveAccountable</h4>
                </a>
            </li>


            <li class="portfolio-box  ">
                <a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fg7iiQ0XGGI&autoplay=1" title="SKRE Extreme Mountain Gear">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/SK-31fqrlv4u0io2bmbt3zfgg.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                    <h4>SKRE Extreme Mountain Gear</h4>
                </a>


            </li>

            <li class="portfolio-box photography">
                <a class="gallery" rel="gallery1" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/SKRE-9-30sp4bav1hxsgwj54nvaww.jpg" title="Concealment">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/SKRE-9-30sp4baun93pvbri4pf1ts.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                    <h4>Concealment</h4>
                </a> 
            </li>



                       <li class="portfolio-box video-production " style="width:338px">
                <a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdxU95byX9E&feature=youtu.be&autoplay=1" title="Why Gold? Why Now?">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/ok-30qtm6hhkfhai4j2g294ao.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                    <h4>Why Gold? Why Now?</h4>
                </a>

            </li>

            <li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:339px">
                <a class="gallery2" rel="gallery2" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img11-30nswp3smpn5synh64xzwg.jpg" title="Random Photography">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img11-30nswp3s8gt37dvu66hqtc.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                    <h4>Random Photography</h4>
                </a>
            </li>



            <li class="portfolio-box photography ">
                <a  class="gallery3" rel="gallery3" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img17-30nswqv4et3spn3ok9j6dc.jpg" title="Sports Photography">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img17-30nswqv40k9q42c1kb2xa8.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                    <h4>Sports Photography</h4>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="portfolio-box photography ">
            <a class="gallery4" rel="gallery4" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img5-30nswmywbqkyk4ynmesum8.jpg" title="Wedding Photography">
                <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img5-30nswmyvxhqvyk70mgclj4.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="mask"></div>
                <div class="line-folio"></div>
                <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                <h4>Wedding Photography</h4>
            </a>
            </li>

            <li class="portfolio-box video-production ">
            <a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbEgxfr3rDE&autoplay=1" title="Why Ashcreek Ranch Academy">
                <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/22-30nstcqe466oswsn6bdla8.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="mask"></div>
                <div class="line-folio"></div>
                <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                <h4>Why Ashcreek Ranch Academy</h4>

            </a>

            </li><li class="portfolio-box video-production ">

            <a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZ-pxEUw6WU&autoplay=1" title="Gold Puplic Investor Promo">

                <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/21-30nssg6u6e4x0cgueyhrls.jpg" alt="" />

                <div class="mask"></div>

                <div class="line-folio"></div>

                <div class="line-folio1"></div>

                <h4>Gold Puplic Investor Promo</h4>

            </a>

            </li><li class="portfolio-box video-production ">

            <a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbmRPENVwLw&autoplay=1" title="Ministering Angels">

                <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/19-30nsqgtk87dygshnmxhc00.jpg" alt="" />

                <div class="mask"></div>

                <div class="line-folio"></div>

                <div class="line-folio1"></div>

                <h4>Ministering Angels</h4>

            </a>

            </li><li class="portfolio-box video-production ">

            <a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SsAgvJFGiGA&autoplay=1" title="Amazing Aerial Video Over the West">

                <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/20-30nsrfvkzu3hubqw3m29s0.jpg" alt="" />

                <div class="mask"></div>

                <div class="line-folio"></div>

                <div class="line-folio1"></div>

                <h4>Amazing Aerial Video Over the West</h4>

            </a>

            </li><li class="portfolio-box video-production ">

            <a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=So4E51xqQB4&autoplay=1" title="Campaign">

                <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/18-30nmv08fhqj2dmq5iibj7k.jpg" alt="" />

                <div class="mask"></div>

                <div class="line-folio"></div>

                <div class="line-folio1"></div>

                <h4>Campaign</h4>

            </a>

            </li>

            <li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
                <a class="gallery" rel="gallery1" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/Mike-Full-Draw-30sp495yqivl82ubkxq5mo.jpg" title="Concealment">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/SKRE-9-30sp4baun93pvbri4pf1ts.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                    <h4>Concealment</h4>
                </a>
            </li>


            <li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
                <a class="gallery2" rel="gallery2" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img16-30nswq8i7cfutedbmxlwcg.jpg" title="Random Photography">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img11-30nswp3s8gt37dvu66hqtc.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                    <h4>Random Photography</h4>
                </a>

            </li>

            <li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
                <a class="gallery2" rel="gallery2" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img13-30nswphd5l8q53w3bqhyps.jpg" title="Random Photography">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img11-30nswp3s8gt37dvu66hqtc.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                    <h4>Random Photography</h4>
</a>
</li>   

<li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
                <a class="gallery2" rel="gallery2" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img15-30nswpzgirdh9avkv78l4w.jpg" title="Random Photography">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img9-30nswoh6f8z7wpx48t0pvk.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                    <h4>Random Photography</h4>
</a>
</li>   

<li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
                <a class="gallery2" rel="gallery2" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img8-30nswo84qnwucmfdh2neo0.jpg" title="Random Photography">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img9-30nswoh6f8z7wpx48t0pvk.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                    <h4>Random Photography</h4>
</a>
</li>   

<li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
                <a class="gallery2" rel="gallery2" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img7-30nswnz322ugsixmpca3gg.jpg" title="Random Photography">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img9-30nswoh6f8z7wpx48t0pvk.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                    <h4>Random Photography</h4>
</a>
</li>   

<li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
                <a class="gallery2" rel="gallery2" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img6-30nswnlij78wgdp0jqq4n4.jpg" title="Random Photography">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img9-30nswoh6f8z7wpx48t0pvk.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                    <h4>Random Photography</h4>
</a>
</li>   

<li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
                <a class="gallery2" rel="gallery2" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img4-30nswmgsykg7fxz62y2874.jpg" title="Random Photography">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img9-30nswoh6f8z7wpx48t0pvk.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                    <h4>Random Photography</h4>
</a>
</li>   

<li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
                <a class="gallery2" rel="gallery2" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img2-30nswlpnwt92rnhxrqyakg.jpg" title="Random Photography">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img9-30nswoh6f8z7wpx48t0pvk.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div> 
                    <h4>Random Photography</h4>
</a>
</li>   

<li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
                <a class="gallery2" rel="gallery2" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img1-30nswl7kjn4bngig8a7o5c.jpg" title="Random Photography">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img9-30nswoh6f8z7wpx48t0pvk.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                    <h4>Random Photography</h4>
</a>
</li>   

<li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
                <a class="gallery2" rel="gallery2" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img24-30nswsqz173medarc9b0g0.jpg" title="Random Photography">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img9-30nswoh6f8z7wpx48t0pvk.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                    <h4>Random Photography</h4>
</a>
</li>   


<li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
                <a class="gallery2" rel="gallery2" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img22-30nsws8vo0yva6b9sske0w.jpg" title="Random Photography">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img9-30nswoh6f8z7wpx48t0pvk.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                    <h4>Random Photography</h4>
</a>
</li>

<li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
                <a class="gallery2" rel="gallery2" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img20-30nswrm9gkaxdxkwvgn400.jpg" title="Random Photography">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img9-30nswoh6f8z7wpx48t0pvk.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                    <h4>Random Photography</h4>
</a>
</li>   

<li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
                <a class="gallery2" rel="gallery2" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img19-30nswrd7rz8jtu363q9ssg.jpg" title="Random Photography">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img9-30nswoh6f8z7wpx48t0pvk.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                    <h4>Random Photography</h4>
</a>
</li>   

<li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
                <a class="gallery2" rel="gallery2" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img18-30nswr463e669qlfbzwhkw.jpg" title="Random Photography">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img9-30nswoh6f8z7wpx48t0pvk.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                    <h4>Random Photography</h4>
</a>
</li>   

<li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
                <a class="gallery2" rel="gallery2" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img16-30nswq8i7cfutedbmxlwcg.jpg" title="Random Photography">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img9-30nswoh6f8z7wpx48t0pvk.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                    <h4>Random Photography</h4>
</a>
</li>   

            <li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
                <a  class="gallery3" rel="gallery3" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img3-30nswm38foun3sqjxci9ds.jpg" title="Sports Photography">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img17-30nswqv40k9q42c1kb2xa8.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                    <h4>Sports Photography</h4>
                </a>
            </li>

       <li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
                <a  class="gallery3" rel="gallery3" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img21-30nswrvb55day12nn70f7k.jpg" title="Sports Photography">
                    <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img17-30nswqv40k9q42c1kb2xa8.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio"></div>
                    <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                    <h4>Sports Photography</h4>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
            <a class="gallery4" rel="gallery4" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img23-30nswsmg6wkfmbjvye4cu8.jpg" title="Wedding Photography">
                <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img5-30nswmyvxhqvyk70mgclj4.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="mask"></div>
                <div class="line-folio"></div>
                <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                <h4>Wedding Photography</h4>
            </a>
            </li>

           <li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
            <a class="gallery4" rel="gallery4" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img12-30nswpcubapjd257xvbb40.jpg" title="Wedding Photography">
                <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img5-30nswmyvxhqvyk70mgclj4.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="mask"></div>
                <div class="line-folio"></div>
                <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                <h4>Wedding Photography</h4>
            </a>
            </li>

  <li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
            <a class="gallery4" rel="gallery4" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img14-30nswpqeu6b3p7du3gv9xc.jpg" title="Wedding Photography">
                <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img5-30nswmyvxhqvyk70mgclj4.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="mask"></div>
                <div class="line-folio"></div>
                <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                <h4>Wedding Photography</h4>
            </a>
            </li>

<li class="portfolio-box photography" style="width:335px;display:none;">
            <a class="gallery4" rel="gallery4" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img10-30nswouqy4ks8v5qeekoow.jpg" title="Wedding Photography">
                <img  src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/img5-30nswmyvxhqvyk70mgclj4.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="mask"></div>
                <div class="line-folio"></div>
                <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                <h4>Wedding Photography</h4>
            </a>
            </li>

            </ul>







    </div>



</div>
```

You can use Chrome's Inspect tool to check the error. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Where is the css part ? could able to share fiddle ?

Comment: the problem is your jquery.

Comment: @Fiido93: How do I fix it?

Comment: does it fix? already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i see your code, and i saw you have elements but are hidden, so you have de big space :)

[image: Check this pic]

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have unordered lists. Have you tried adding:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

it might clear your floats maybe that's the reason?

Comment: Hmm. I don't it will work. Have you tried inpecting the elements using Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Look, they are yout hidden elements
[image: check this pic]